# How can I create a template in realm?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I want to create a new template in realm for sync.

Because default template using Partition Based in sync type. But I want to Flexible sync type.

Can I change that type when template creating?

or

Can I create a new app template in realm that includes flexible sync?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by a "template"? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Didn't you know realm template. I found it in atlas app service documents. This is a link about that documentation - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/template-apps/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The question asked about [Creating a Template](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/template-apps/#create-a-template-app) which is covered in the docs. Note *The template apps come with a frontend that uses the appropriate Realm Database SDK. The prebuilt app is a ToDo app similar to the Task Tracker app in the tutorial*. To use Flexible Sync, start with the Task Tracker Tutorial and modify the sync sections for [Flexible Sync](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/examples/flexible-sync/?_ga=2.224321496.27525587.1654952635-1381050191.1644589707)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a template in local and I push it using realm cli.